# Does anyone know where I can find a set of online Ruby programming sets/exercises?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am searching for a set of problems, a book of exercises or challenges for Ruby and/or Ruby on Rails. The resources that I found appear to be offline or outdated. I see recommendations for Ruby Quiz, but the site seems dead. Any help would be much appreciated.

I completed the Ruby series on Codecademy, and am starting with the pickaxe book Programming Ruby 1.9 & 2.0. It's mostly a tutorial book with no exercises or challenged though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Project Euler is pretty solid (http://projecteuler.net/) as are Ruby Koans (http://rubykoans.com/). You can try "Learn Ruby the Hard Way" as well.

As far as Rails exercises, I'd say "Learn Rails by Example" by Michael Hartl (Which is free and easy to find online).

Comment: Thanks ace, Project Euler seems really awesome. Haven't looked into Koans yet, but I will :)

Answer (score 2):

Start with http://betterexplained.com/articles/starting-ruby-on-rails-what-i-wish-i-knew/

Then you may like using [Code Academy](http://www.codecademy.com/#!/exercises/0) and [Code School](http://www.codeschool.com/).

Ryan Bates [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/) are must for anyone learning rails.

Some folks also like the irreverence behind [Rails for Zombies](http://railsforzombies.org/)

[Peepcodes](https://peepcode.com/screencasts/ruby-on-rails) have quite a few including rspec testing

Many have used [Michael Hartl's tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) so if you get stuck there's lots of help available on sites like SO.

Other advice on versions and dates:
For Ruby, use 1.9 (instead of 1.8.x) and don't worry if it's five years old.
For Rails, use 3.1+ and so tutorials need to be from the last 2 years.

Comment: Thank you for your input Michael. I was looking for challenges though, but I'll definitely be following the railscasts.

Answer (score 1):

An awesome site, on which I am learning regularly is:

http://www.codequizzes.com/

Answer (score 0):

I first began learning on http://rubymonk.com/ , but there are also some other interactive tutorials like http://tryruby.org/ you could try out.